# How do we talk to bitcoind in a PHP plugin?

Tags: bitcoind, php

I'm trying to write a PHP plugin that will talk to bitcoind to generate a random address to send a bitcoin transaction to.

I'm really confused: how am I supposed to setup bitcoind so that we can query it to generate a random address?

Thanks!

Comment: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/PHP_developer_intro

Answer (score 2):

First, run `bitcoind` on your server. Set up `bitcoin.conf` to have the correct RPC port and a password and etc.

Then, include the jsonRPCClient.php file:

```
include('jsonRPCClient.php');
```

Then, instantiate an object like so:

```
$bitcoind = new jsonRPCClient("http://$YOUR_RPC_USER:$YOUR_RPC_PASS@$YOUR_RPC_HOST:$YOUR_RPC_PORT/");
```

You can now run commands from the RPC using this object.

```
$bitcoind->getnetworkhashps();
$bitcoind->getrawtransaction($txid);
```

So if you want a new address:

```
$newaddr = $bitcoind->getnewaddress();
```

Answer (score 0):

bitcoind - d for daemon. It has a native JSON-RPC API built in to it, indeed that's what it provides. You simply use JSON-RPC calls to get information out of bitcoind, or indeed to send information to bitcoind.

- [JSON-RPC API Reference](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_%28JSON-RPC%29)
- [PHP Developer Intro](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/PHP_developer_intro)
- [Bitcoin + PHP search on GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=bitcoin+php)