# Is there a gui to manage the bitcoind server via a browser?

Tags: wallet, bitcoind

I installed bitcoind on my centos server and was wondering if there was a gui that can control everything the bitcoind does. Would be nice check balance, send funds, create wallets via the browser.

Comment: Note: I approved (at least, improved) the edit on this question, but in hindsight it should have been rejected (I mistakenly thought the author edited it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks, like it is 50 strings php file:

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/PHP_developer_intro

See, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/13849/how-do-we-talk-to-bitcoind-in-a-php-plugin

Also, read this http://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/1tvn12/best_way_to_programatically_receive_and_send/

For the rest, https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoin-python